# Android Record Voice and Call at back end

Tags: android, call, voice, recorder

Is it possible that android application runs in background and record the voice and all the incoming and outgoing calls?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it, but by law in the United States, you will need to play a beep ever so often at regular intervals or have an announcement before you start recording, see the link.

www.fcc.gov/guides/recording-telephone-conversations